# Jest - react-native SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I am running jest test in react native and it fails giving "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"

Here is my trimmer import code: -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container,
  Content,
  Text,
  Button,
  Icon,
  Footer,
  FooterTab,
  Item,
  Input,
  View,
  Picker
} from 'native-base';

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
```

Here is error:

FAIL  **tests**/home-page-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/Users/myuser/sampleApp/node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import connectStyle from "./src/connectStyle";
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

  1 | import React, { Component } from 'react';
> 2 | import {
    | ^
  3 |   Header,
  4 |   Title,
  5 |   Button,
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong in import. Any tips are most welcomed.

Comment: can you post the package.json ? check out this link https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/396#issuecomment-270116326

Comment: have this same bug currently, will update if i find a fix

Answer (score 0):

I kwnow it's late, but for people that are still looking for a solution [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/977) is described how to fix this

Just add this snippet to your jest config file:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|native-base-shoutem-theme|@shoutem/animation|@shoutem/ui|tcomb-form-native)"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In two projects I upgraded from Angular 12 to 14 and 15. Both projects failed with the error message of the "unexpected token".

Did many jest config changes according to step-by-step guides. With transform ignore stuff as well.

Finally solved ALL this in both projects by just upgrading the 'rxjs' to a more recent version. The transform rules were not needed at all.

Both projects run well again!

My package dependencies are:

```
"@types/jest": "^29.2.5",
"jest": "^28.1.3",
"jest-preset-angular": "^12.2.3",
"ng-mocks": "^14.11.0",
"rxjs": "~7.5.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
```